# Default date to display in date text box using Date Picker

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the below for Jquery datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Custom/jQueryDatePicker/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Custom/jQueryDatePicker/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="Custom/jQueryDatePicker/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='Form_Header_ExtraSpaceAbove'><p class='Form_Header'>Select Date</p>

<input type="text" id="datepicker" style="width:200px;" readonly="true" title="Select date"><br><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


    var varName = "Date";

    var today = new Date();

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({

    showOn: 'button', 
    buttonImageOnly: true, 
    showOn: "both",
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { FormSetFieldValue(varName, dateText); },
    buttonImage: 'Custom/jQueryDatePicker/cal.jpg',
    dateFormat: "d MM yy",
    buttonText: "Pick a date"
    });

    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
            $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
    });

    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").css("margin", "0px 0px -10px 0px");

    $("#datepicker").val(FormGetFieldValue(varName));


});



function FormGetFieldValue (fieldName)
{
    return PFSF_GetFieldValueByName("FIELD_" + FieldIDs[fieldName]);
}

function FormSetFieldValue (fieldName, fieldValue)
{
    PFSF_SetControlValue(PFSF_Find('FIELD_' + FieldIDs[fieldName]), fieldValue);
}


</script>
</div>
```

But I am not able to set the default date to display in the text box when the form loads. The date appears in the date text box only when I click the calendar icon and select the date.

So please help me to display today's date by default in the date text field when the form loads so that the date text box is not blank until I pick at date.

Comment: The date has to be in the format you specified, "d MM yy". If not then you need to convert it to that format

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$("#datepicker").val(FormGetFieldValue(varName));
```

by

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate',FormGetFieldValue(varName));
```

Answer (score 0):

just add `.datepicker("setDate", new Date());` in the end. Live jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tDLcC/

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({

    showOn: 'button', 
    buttonImageOnly: true, 
    showOn: "both",
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { FormSetFieldValue(varName, dateText); },
    buttonImage: 'Custom/jQueryDatePicker/cal.jpg',
    dateFormat: "d MM yy",
    buttonText: "Pick a date"
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```